# How to properly link C++ model to QML front end

Tags: qt, qml

here is my setup:

First is the model class, this stores a pointer to the data of type `CompetitionsList`. We can see that it implements the necessary basic functions when deriving from `QAbstractListModel`, and it uses the `QML_ELEMENT` macro to expose the model to the QML type system:

```
class CompetitionsListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(CompetitionsList* list READ list WRITE setList)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    explicit CompetitionsListModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    enum {
        NameRole = Qt::ItemDataRole(),
        IdRole
    };

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    CompetitionsList *list() const;
    void setList(CompetitionsList *list);

    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

private:
    CompetitionsList* m_list;  \\ <--- ptr to data
};
```

Then we have the data class. This class is also a `QML_ELEMENT`, and it has a `userid` property. This is used to populate the `QVector<listItem>` by requesting data from a RESTful http server.

The two signals `preItemAppended()` and `postItemAppended()` are emitted when data is added to the `QVector<listItem>`. These signals are then connected to the Model as a way of notifying the model it must create a new row in the list. The important function here is `populateCompetitions`, which I explain below.

```
struct listItem {
    QString competitionName;
    QString competitionId;
};

class CompetitionsList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString userId READ getUserId WRITE setUserId)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    explicit CompetitionsList(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void populateCompetitions(const QString& userId);
    QVector<listItem> items();
    QString getUserId() const;
    void setUserId(const QString &value);

signals:
    void preItemAppended();
    void postItemAppended();
    void errorPopulatingData();
private:
    QVector<listItem> m_competitions;
    QString userId;
};
```

The `populateCompetitions` function looks as so:

```
void CompetitionsList::populateCompetitions(const QString &userId)
{
    qDebug() << "initialising data";
    HttpClient* client = new HttpClient();
    client->getUserCompetitions(userId);

    connect(client, &HttpClient::getUserCompetitionsResult, [=](const QByteArray& reply){
        QJsonDocument _reply = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply);

        if(_reply["data"].isNull()) {
            emit errorPopulatingData();
        }
        else {
            const QJsonArray competitions = _reply["data"]["competitions"].toArray();
            for(const QJsonValue& competition : competitions) {
                emit preItemAppended();

                listItem item{competition["competition-name"].toString(), competition["competition-id"].toString()};
                m_competitions.append(std::move(item));

                emit postItemAppended();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It requests data from the database, and then stores it locally.

Then finally, the QML model which ties it all together:

```
ListView {
        id: view
        implicitHeight: 1920
        implicitWidth: 1080
        clip: true

        model: CompetitionsListModel {
            list: CompetitionsList {
                id: compList
            }
            Component.onCompleted: { compList.userId = "6033f377257e8630ed13299e" } //<-- calls the populateCompetitions function
        }

        delegate: RowLayout {
            Text {
                text: qsTr(model.name + ":::" + model.id)
            }
        }
    }
```

We can see that it has a `ListView` element, with a model of type `CompetitionsListModel` and a list of type `CompetitionsList`. Once the model component is created, we set the userId of the list, this in turn calls the `populateCompetitions` function which sets up the data for the model to use as seen above.

Unfortunately this doesnt anything when I run the code. Blank screen. Nada. I was wondering if anyone has an insight as to what might be causing this based on the code provided. Ive been at it for so long and it just inst being nice.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do you have any warning or error from QML in run time?

Comment: I doubt it is the problem, but I would put `client->getUserCompetitions(userId);` after the connect. How is the `preItemAppended` connected in the QAbstractListModel-derived class?

Comment: can you provide your setList method implementation?

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan no worries, I have moved on. Will close the question

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to call qmlRegisterType or UncreatableType on your CompetitionsListModel :
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType

Comment: he uses QML_ELEMENT, which is a replacement for qmlRegisterType for Qt 5.15

Comment: I think QML_Element and Qt5.xx is buggy. Use old valid way as mentioned above